# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints when update height constraints of imageView swift 4

Tags: ios, tableview, swift4, uistackview

I have a `stack view` that look like the figure below:

[image]

So I change the height of the `image` programmatically to make it fit the image that download from my server,if dont have image,the height constraints of `image` will set to be zero.

Here is my code to doing so:

```
    let imageUrl = URL(string :imageString)

    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl!)
    {

       guard let actualImage: UIImage = UIImage(data: data) else{
        print("No image!")
        ImageView.image = nil
       defaultImageHeightContrainst = ImageHeightContrainst.constant
       ImageHeightContrainst.constant = 0

        layoutIfNeeded()
        return
      }

     let imageHeight = actualImage.size.height * actualImage.scale
     print("imageHeight = \(imageHeight)")
     defaultImageHeightContrainst = ImageHeightContrainst.constant
     ImageHeightContrainst.constant = imageHeight

     layoutIfNeeded()

     //here display the image to the imageview
      ImageView.kf.setImage(with: imageUrl)

   }
```

With the code above,the image height is scale according to actual image height which download from internet.If dont have image,the "image" part also set to 0 already.

This is what I expected,but now I face an error below whenever the "image" height become taller in order to fit the actual image height

```
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080002868b0 UIImageView:0x7f9cbae59240.height == 50   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000286bd0 UIView:0x7f9cbae5ad80.height == 1   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000286d10 UIImageView:0x7f9cbae5b440.height == 458   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000286f90 UIView:0x7f9cbae5bb50.height == 1   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080002871c0 V:|-(0)-[UILabel:0x7f9cbae5b160]   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7f9cbae5af60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000287350 V:[UILabel:0x7f9cbae5b160]-(10)-[UIImageView:0x7f9cbae5b440]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080002873a0 V:[UIImageView:0x7f9cbae5b440]-(10)-[UIStackView:0x7f9cbae5b670]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000287580 V:[UIStackView:0x7f9cbae5b670]-(10)-[UIView:0x7f9cbae5bb50]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080002875d0 V:[UIStackView:0x7f9cbae5c0f0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7f9cbae5af60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000287670 V:[UIView:0x7f9cbae5bb50]-(10)-[UIStackView:0x7f9cbae5c0f0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080002877b0 V:|-(10)-[UIImageView:0x7f9cbae59240]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f9cbae5a0c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080002878f0 V:[UIImageView:0x7f9cbae59240]-(8)-[UIView:0x7f9cbae5ad80]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080002879e0 V:[UIStackView:0x7f9cbae5af60]-(10)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f9cbae5a0c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000287a80 V:[UIView:0x7f9cbae5ad80]-(8)-[UIStackView:0x7f9cbae5af60]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000288c00 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7f9cbae5c0f0.top == _UILayoutSpacer:0x6080001cd5c0'UISV-alignment-spanner'.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000288ca0 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[_UILayoutSpacer:0x6080001cd5c0'UISV-alignment-spanner']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7f9cbae5c0f0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000289970 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f9cbae5a0c0.height == 476.5   (active)>"
)
```

Before asking,I already checked all my other constraints,which is all set correctly.I even disable all the code that can change the height of "image",once disable,there is no problem.The error only occurred when I intend to change the height.

I even tried to add `ImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` before `layoutIfNeeded()`,but the error is still exist.

So what is the correct way to change the height of image in order to fit the actual image download from server?

Comment: Can u share the complete log in console for constraints

Comment: @Sh_Khan bro already update

Comment: What distribution type have you got set for the UIStackView?

Comment: by any chance, is the stackview inside of a `UITableViewCell` that uses `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to compute its height automatically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Considering that the last constraint says

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000289970 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f9cbae5a0c0.height == 476.5   (active)>"
```

I assume you are using `stackView` inside of a `UITableViewCell` to implement automatic height cells in a `tableView`. If my assumption is correct, then the problem is not with the `stackView`, nor with the `imageView`, but with the way `UITableView` works with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and Autolayout. If the layout works as you expect, and the warning is the only thing that bugs you, then read following.

Therefore it seems to me that this is a result of an known "bug" - there is a collision of the height set by the `tableView` and the height calculated by the autolayout. When rendering the cell, the `tableView` first applies the default height, calculates the autolayout height, and then use the latter - at least it seems so. See my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44651241/expandable-tableview-cell-using-autolayout-results-in-uiviewalertforunsatisfiabl). The constraint mentioned above (`'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height'`) is the one applied by the `UITableView` that later goes away.

That means that the constraints you are using are probably OK. Just set one of the constraints defining height to `priority = 999` (so that until it deactivates the default height constraint it won't cause any conflict). In the end, it will result in using your constraint anyway, so it will not cause any layout trouble.

E.g., if you constrain the `stackView` to fit the cell's `contentView`, set the `stackView.bottomAnchor` to `contentView.bottomAnchor` just with the priority set to 999. If you did the layout programmatically, this might be your solution:

```
let bottomConstraint = tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
bottomConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    // rest of the constraints
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
    stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor),
    stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor),
    bottomConstraint,
])
```

If you do the layout in storyboards, just select appropriate constraint in the storyboards, and in the attributes inspector set its priority to 999 (for example):

[image: Settings constraint's priority to 999]