# set line spacing of static cells of tableview with storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I want to know if there is a way to set the spacing between rows with static cells of tableview with storyboard.

I didn't find an attributor to do that:

[image]

I want to set the spacing between rows so it should like this:

[image]

Comment: There is no spacing between cells in a table view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do that. There are several options how you can deal with this.

1. Simulate the separator in the cell itself (e.g., see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48135951/2912282)).
2. Use every other cell as a separator (so cell at row 0 will be normal cell, cell at row 1 will be a separator, cell at row 2 a normal cell, etc.).
3. Use section footers as a separators, in that case there will be section per every cell - `numberOfSections` will return number of all cells, `numberOfRows` will return 1. Then use `footerForSection` to provide appropriate "separator".

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in attribute inspector to do that , you can do it like that

```
contentView
     topView   ----- height(static) ---- white background
     spaceView ----- height (5) ---- gray background
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UICollectionView`

`UITableView` don't provide spacing between rows